# apachesolr search form block that points to search page

Tags: 7, search

I have a custom search page configured in apachesolr_search module which displays only products as results (bundle:product_display). I want to create a simple block that contains an input field for a keyword and the submit button, and when the user submits the form it should direct to the specific search page.

I haven't found an easy way to do that. Other developers seem to modify the core block search form, but this does not help as I will have the same requirement in many pages over the same website (many apachesolr search blocks pointing to different apachesolr pages).

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue queue asking for such feature:
https://drupal.org/node/326375

I also found a module (a sandbox) for Drupal7 to export for each search-page a search-block:
https://drupal.org/sandbox/incrn8/1315802